# Swift access to a file that is stored in another folder

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a app, where you can record videos or images. You can record videos or images on your own or you can pick it from the UIImagePicker. The videos/images are listed in a collection view. 
When you tab on a row in the collection view it shows the image or the video.

One thing I don't understand is, if I record a video to safe it, it shows up in the collection view, but when I choose the video that I recorded before, I only see a grey background and not the actually video.

If I choose a video from the gallery it shows up and play.

This is how I display the video

```
player = AVPlayer(url: arrayOfVideoUrls[i]!)
                print(arrayOfVideoUrls[i]!)
                playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
                playerLayer?.frame = view.frame
                view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)
                player?.play()
```

My guess is, that I can't open the video, because it is saved in another folder.

This is the folder of my self recorded Video:

file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E0EBF7F9-713C-451B-B764-D2056ECC6E48/tmp/7834C1AF-1417-4389-B455-92DA52DFF93F.mov

This is the folder of the video from the gallery:

file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/1A977F99-6C5C-40F7-933D-E325D8E967E4/tmp/trim.31B4A909-E8FA-4CBE-B64F-30646A6366B3.MOV

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the path whenever you save your recorded video and after saving you need to check that path whether its containing file or not.
And Please make sure, you give different name to your recording whenever you record a new video.And to play that video append the name of video with the path.

Comment: can you give me an example?